# ClassNotFoundException for ripple effect when added QR code scanner lib the error only in samsung note-4

Tags: android, ripple

When adding dependencies for the QR code scanner `me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4`, it causes the following error in Ripple effect lib `com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3`.

I got this error message in Samsung Note 4 (KitKat), it works in some other phone.
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com......RippleView"`

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple) library for ripple effect or prefix the library resources using the new android gradle option to avoid name clashes with other libraries:

```
android {
  resourcePrefix 'mylib_'
}
```